# Passing Javascript Variables to PHP function

Tags: javascript, php, get

I am trying to get my Javascript variables passed back to my PHP function. I am aware that I need to use the GET method but am unsure how to implement it here.

**My PHP Function:**

```
function showRailroadSchedule()
{
    global $conn;
    global $thisPHP;

    $sql = "SELECT * FROM trip";
    $result = $conn->query($sql);

    if ($result->num_rows > 0) 
    {         
        echo '<div class="limiter">';
        echo '<div class="container-table100">';
        echo '<div class="wrap-table100">';
        echo '<div class="table100 ver2 m-b-110">';
        echo "<h2>Available Trip Reservations</h2>";
        echo '<table data-vertable="ver2" id="tableMain">';
        echo "<thead><tr class='row100 head'><th>Trip ID</th><th>Arrival Time</th><th>Departure Time</th><th>Train ID</th><th>Arrival Station</th><th>Track ID</th><th>Departure Station</th></tr></thead>"; 
        while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) 
        {
            echo '<tbody><tr class="row100">';
            $TRIP_ID = $row["TRIP_ID"];
            echo  
                  ' <td class="column100 column2" data-column="column2"> ' . $row["TRIP_ID"] .
                  ' </td> <td class="column100 column3" data-column="column3"> ' . $row["TRIP_ARR_TIME"] .
                  ' </td> <td class="column100 column4" data-column="column4"> ' . $row["TRIP_DEP_TIME"] . 
                  ' </td> <td class="column100 column5" data-column="column5"> ' . $row["TRAIN_ID"] . 
                  '</td>  <td class="column100 column6" data-column="column6"> ' . $row["TS_ARRIVAL"] . 
                  '</td>  <td class="column100 column7" data-column="column7"> ' . $row["TRACK_ID"] .
                  '</td>  <td class="column100 column8" data-column="column8"> ' . $row["TS_DEPARTURE"] .
                  '</td> '; 

            echo "<form action='{$thisPHP}' method='post' style='display:inline' >";
            echo "<input type='hidden' name='cID' value='{$cID}'>";
            echo "</td></tr></tbody>";

        }

        echo "<tfoot><tr><td>'$_GET[w1]'</td><td>Arrival Time</td><td>Departure Time</td><td>Train ID</td><td>Arrival Station</td><td>Track ID</td><td>Departure Station</td></tr></tfoot>";
        echo "</table>";
        echo "</div>";
        echo "</div>";
        echo "</div>";
        echo "</div>";     
    }

    else 
    {
        echo "0 results";
    }

}
```

**My Javascript Function:**

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        //=================================================================
        //click on table body
        //$("#tableMain tbody tr").click(function () {
        $('#tableMain tbody').on('click', 'tr', function() {
            //get row contents into an array
            var tableData = $(this).children("td").map(function() {
                return $(this).text();  
            }).get();
            var tripid = tableData[0];
            var arrivaltime= tableData[1];
            var departuretime = tableData[2];
            var trainid = tableData[3];
            var arrivalstation = tableData[4];
            var trackid = tableData[5];
            var departurestation = tableData[6];
            //var arrivaltime = tableData[1] + '*' + tableData[2] + '*' + tableData[3] + '*' + tableData[4] + '*' + tableData[5] + '*' + tableData[6] + '*' + tableData[7];
            alert(tripid);
            window.location.href = "railroadutils.php?w1=" + tripid;

        });

        $("#thebutton").click(function() {
            $('#tableMain > tbody').append('<tr class="datarow"><td>11111</td><td>22222</td><td>33333</td><td>44444</td><td>55555</td></tr>')
        })
    });

</script>
```

After a row is clicked, the page refreshes and a blank screen appears, however the link does have the w1 variable in it. I am just wanting to display this w1 variable inside my table.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Issue resolved. Did not use the right php file name in the javascript function

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing the rendered HTML, it's hard to see what's happening but I think this is your issue:

```
echo "<tfoot><tr><td>'$_GET[w1]'</td><td>Arrival Time</td><td>Departure Time</td><td>...
                     ^^^^^^^^^^^
```

I think you need to concatenate it like you did the other echo statements like this:

```
echo "<tfoot><tr><td>'" . $_GET[w1] . "'</td><td>Arrival Time</td><td>Departure Time</td><td>...
                      ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

Comment: I have figured it the issue. I wasn't calling the right php file in javascript function. I have changed this concatenation issue, however it was still working as I had it originally. Thanks for the help!